# Низкое разрешение в VM VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox

Ноутбук с Windows8.1. 
Установил на него Oracle VM VirtualBox. Создал виртуальную машину и установил на нее ubuntu 14.04. Проблема в том, что доступно только одно разрешение - 640х480. Увеличил в настройках виртуальной машины видеопамять до 128мб, но без толку. Как можно увеличить разрешение?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно внутри гостевой ОС установить [Guest Additions](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html). Для этого нужно подключить CD диск с дополнениями (делается из меню VB) и запустить скрипт, который расположен на нем.

Comment: подправьте *additions

Comment: http://virtualboxes.org/doc/installing-guest-additions-on-ubuntu/ - устанавливал по этой инструкции, она короче и понятнее